# How to create a tab without navigation capability

Tags: javascript, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm working on an add-on where most of the content/user interface is hosted in a tab that I open up with the 'tabs' API.  I'd really like my tab not to have a bookmarks or address bar, and to forbid navigation away from the content I have specified there.  Is there a way to produce a 'naked' tab without these elements, or to strip them from an existing tab?  The tab that hosts the add-ons manager in Firefox itself is a good example of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the addon-page module:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/addon-page.html

This is a relatively new module, so if you run into issues or have requests for additional functionality the project would appreciate feedback.

Feel free to post to the google group ( https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mozilla-labs-jetpack ) or the #jetpack channel on irc.mozilla.org.